# Looping over a container as a template

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I am a little bit new to template programming in C++ and have gotten stuck. I am trying to write a piece of code to loop over elements in a container and template type T. What I have is clearly wrong but I think should get the idea across.

```
template <typename Container, typename T >
Container<T> MyFunction(Container<T> input)
{
    T precedingElement = input[0];
    Container<T> output = input;       
    for(int i=1; i<input.size(); i++)
    {
        // Do some work on element in the container
        // Now update precedingElement
        precedingElement = input[i];
    }
    return output;
}

// Example
vector<float> a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...];
vector<float> b = MyFunction(a);
// Another example
list<MyType> c = [object1, object2, ... ];
list<MyType> d = MyFunction(c)
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, accept function arguments you don't want to modify by `const` reference, to avoid a potentially expensive copy:
    template 
    Container MyFunction(const Container& input)

In the implementation below, the elements are tracked using *iterators*, which all Standard Library containers support, so you can operate on `std::list<>`s, `std::vector<>`s, even `std::string`s.

```
{
    Container<T> output = input;
    Container<T>::const_iterator in_it = input.begin();

    for (Container<T>::iterator out_it = std::next(output.begin());
         out_it != output.end(); ++out_it, ++in_it)
        *out_it += *in_it;

    return output;
}

// Example
vector<float> a = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...};
vector<float> b = MyFunction(a);
// Another example
list<MyType> c = { object1, object2, ... };
list<MyType> d = MyFunction(c);
```

Comment: if I have vector A = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, ...] and I want to generate another vector B where the elements b_i are equal to a_i + a_(i-1) for i = 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Comment: Then you'd say `output[i] += input[i - 1];` inside the `for` loop (***instead*** of the `output[i-1] = input[i];` above).

Comment: For that example that is correct and the best way to get the answer, I was trying to make that an example of the algorithm not the best approach for adding numbers. The actual problem is unwrapping phase a measurement and it can't depend on one kind of container. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: *"can't depend on one kind of container"* - fair enough - I hadn't paid attention to your `list<MyType>` example, and `std::list<>`s can't be randomly accessed (i.e. with `[n]` notation), so I've rewritten the code to use iterators and explained why....

Comment: You are correct again, I was incorrectly using list. What would be the iterator way of solving this problem? That seems like it would be more general.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `precedingElement` update should read `precedingElement = input[i]` (it is of element type, not a collection)

Comment: You are correct, my mistake. I copy and pasted it from my code and the type T is indexable also. It does not help my point and sorry for the complication.

Comment: The problem is that `vector` itself is not a type, but a template, and you should declare it as template template parameter: `template<template<class>  Container, class T>`

Comment: Can you provide an example? I am not sure that I understand, Thanks

Comment: use `template < template<typename> Container, typename T >Container<T> MyFunction(Container<T> input) { ` in function declaration

Comment: For some reason I am having trouble with "template < template<typename> Container, typename T >" but "template<typename T, template<typename> class Container>" just fine. Go figure, but I think that maybe it, Thanks for the help